# Translating javascript to java

Tags: javascript, java

I have been working on turning a large javascript program into java. However I am unsure what is happening in these few lines here and how to turn it into java.

```
    int val = 0; //already turned to java

    int o = hash.length() % 4;  //already turned to java

for (var i = o > 0 ? o - 4 : 0; i < hash.length; i += 4) {
        val = ((val << 16) + parseInt(hash.substring(i, i+4), 16)) % mod;
    }
```

It is for a divisible function. hash is a string (specifically a sha256 string hash). Anyone able to help me figure out this weird forloop? Thanks.

I am aware that the parseInt is turning it into base 16, as I have translated that part other places in the code.

Comment: The for-clause is just a ternary operator to set i to either o - 4 or to 0. The `<<` part is a bitwise operator, but I'm not 100% sure what the result of that calculation is.

Comment: [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html), [Java Conditional Operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html), [Integer.parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)). Apart from the parseInt usage, the only non-Java syntax there is the `var i`, which would become `int i`. And of course `hash.length` becomes `hash.length()`.

Comment: My lack of understanding was never seeing bitwise and bit shift operators before, thank you for clearing this up @nbrooks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for i = o
where o is greater than zero . else o-4 is set as 0

till
i  less than hash.length

iterate
i by 4 each time

In the loop each time :
val is equal to -

val left shift by 16 bits
plus
remainder of the integer value with a base 16 of (ith element of hash to the i+4 element ) and "mod"

you have not provided any definition for mod.

The substring() method extracts the characters from a string, between two specified indices, and returns the new sub string.

This method extracts the characters in a string between "start" and "end", not including "end" itself.

If "start" is greater than "end", this method will swap the two arguments, meaning str.substring(1,4) == str.substring(4,1).

If either "start" or "stop" is less than 0, it is treated as if it were 0.

[parseInt() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

It parses the input as an integer plus the second argument specifies the radix, that is base of the number system in this case its a hex

[Bitwise left Shift, the << operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)

val as i'm guessing is already a value in the hexadecimal number system so this basically in the decimal system would be like a minus 1

[Ternary operator , your for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

The only operator which can take three arguments, basically short hand for an if{} else{} loop .

Answer (score -1):

```
int val = 0; //already turned to java

int o = hash.length() % 4;  //already turned to java

for (int i = o > 0 ? o - 4 : 0; i < hash.length; i += 4) {
    val = ((val << 16) + Integer.parseInt(hash.substring(i, i+4), 16)) % mod;
}
```

This is the java code

Comment: This won't compile, nor does it answer the question of what the code is doing.

Comment: @nbrooks "how to turn it into java" - this is the answer for this part of the question. The functional stuff is already in the comments